# Cannot console log DRF error message in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm struggling to figure out how to console log an error I am getting from my django-rest framework. This is what I currently have

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const user = {
        username: data.username,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        profile: {
                    city: data.city,
                    country: data.country,
        }
    };
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
            .then((data) => {
            })
            .catch((resp)=>{console.log(resp)})
    };
```

This is an example of an error I am getting:

```
{"username":["A user with that username already exists."]}
```

This is a `400 Error`

Answer (score 0):

this is your `console.log()` ==>  `{"username":["A user with that username already exists."]}` to catch your `error` message from your server. If your goal is to test your application. Don't use the same username or clear the user from the database first.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that the error message was in a promise so I had to resolve the promise to be able to console the error message:

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const user = {
        username: data.username,
        email: data.email,
        password: data.password,
        profile: {
                    city: data.city,
                    country: data.country,
        }
    };
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(user)
        })
        .then(res => {
            if(!res.ok){
               return res.text().then(text=> {console.log(text) })
            }
            else {
                return res.json().then(data=> {console.log(data) })
                }}) }
```